# Geometric intuition for how ridge ($L_2$) regularization helps under multicollinearity

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, intuition, ridge-regression, geometry

We have some nice posts ([1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322017/an-intuitive-explanation-why-correlated-predictors-will-inflate-the-beta/322030#322030), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/545148/why-is-multicollinearity-different-than-correlation/545152#545152) and likely more) illustrating multicollinearity geometrically. Now, ridge regression ($L_2$ regularization) is known to be a remedy of multicollinearity. What is the geometric intuition for that?

We have a nice answer [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151304/why-is-ridge-regression-called-ridge-why-is-it-needed-and-what-happens-when/151351#151351) that illustrates the geometry of the objective function and shows how a ridge under OLS becomes a peak under ridge regression. **In addition to that**, would it be possible to illustrate the geometry of **fitting a plane in a 3D space** (as in [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322017/an-intuitive-explanation-why-correlated-predictors-will-inflate-the-beta/322030#322030)) with OLS vs. ridge when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are (almost) collinear? **Or perhaps use yet another geometric perspective** that provides intuition?

Comment: Isn't https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/164546/919 good enough?

Comment: @whuber, I guess it is. Thank you! I had overlooked it in my search. When I am trying to picture it in my head, can I imagine the mean of $y$ is zero and the $X$ matrix does not contain a columns of 1s? (Otherwise I am having a hard time. It then seems that adding the ridge terms is making the best fitting hyperplane steeper if the mean of $y$ is positive.)